# Rotation matrix between two frames

Tags: transformation, rotations

Frame A:

[image]

Frame B:

[image]

(x1 in frame A is perpendicular to the plane created by x2 and x3 and x3 in frame B is perpendicular to the plane created by x1 and x2)

I am trying to find the rotation matrix from A to B. I know that in order to do this, I need to write the unit vectors of B in terms of the coordinates of A so that:
$$R_{AB} = \begin{bmatrix} (R_{AB})_1 & (R_{AB})_2 & (R_{AB})_3\end{bmatrix}$$
How can I write the unit vectors of B in terms of coordinates of A with this little given info?

Comment: So you've left the $x_1$-axis alone and rotated the $x_2x_3$-plane by $\pi/4$? I don't understand the meaning of the rotated plane in your pictures.

Comment: x1 in frame A is perpendicular to the plane created by x2 and x3 and x3 in frame B is perpendicular to the plane created by x1 and x2

Comment: Is the $x_1$-axis the same in both cases? The new $x_2'$-axis is in the original $x_2x_3$-plane, rotated by $\pi/4$?

Comment: I am given these images and I am assuming that x1 is the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still find the description a bit vague. But if we take $e_1=(1,0,0)$, $e_2=(0,1,0)$, and $e_3=(0,0,1)$, then the new coordinate basis should be $e_1' = e_1$, $e_2' = (0,1/\sqrt2,1/\sqrt2)$, and $e_3'=(0,-1/\sqrt2,1/\sqrt2)$. Thus, the rotation matrix should be
$$R = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1/\sqrt2 & -1/\sqrt2 \\ 0 & 1/\sqrt2 & 1/\sqrt2\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: oh wait, this is just a rotation around one of the axis, I totally see and get it now, thanks!

Comment: Yup, it is, if *in fact* the $x_1$-axis is fixed. The diagram is sloppy.